# Magento error after trying to enable System >Tools> Compilation

Tags: magento

I am on Magento 1.7 CE, & to speed up the site, went to System >Tools> Compilation and hit Enable. And my site is down!

First, which file on the server do I change to fix this?
Second, is it true that you do not Enable this ever, but rather just click on 'Run Compilation Process'? And if so, how often?

Thanks.
-TM

Comment: turn off compilation via ssh first with "php shell/compiler.php disable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to run compilation first. Than you can leave it like that, as long as you do not update you code. When you update (f.i. using svn update) you'll need to recompile again in orde for it to work with the new code.

Disabled is possible as in the comment aboven, or by commenting

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

In the folder: `/includes/config.php`

Comment: Thanks, I disabled using your method (manual) and then manually cleared my caches. The site is up. I am confused about the Run Compilation: are you saying that I do not have to click on Enable at all, & simply click 'Run Compilation'? And everytime I make some changes to the code, run it again?

Comment: If you have a look at the compiled files, you'll see that your code is present in another folder and that Magento will use that code instead of the original. That's why you'll have to recompile after every update in your code (otherwise, Magento will use an old compiled version instead of the new uncompiled code). Not sure  anymore if you have to enable after compiling, you'll have to check if it says it's enabled or not (may be done automatically).